# Shortcut to convert single-line bracketed lists to be multi-line in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I spend a lot of time having to manually expand brackets in VSCode, for example:

```
something.some_function(variable_1, variable_2, variable_3)
```

I want this to look like:

```
something.some_function(
  variable_1,
  variable_2,
  variable_3
)
```

Is there a shortcut to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this extension for a while and i believe it works for your request.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenzhe.split-line

Im not using this tool but its used a lot:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: Thanks, while the extension does work, it doesn't remove the need to manually edit lines as I have to manually indent each line once they have been converted. Prettier does work for JS code but I am looking for something universal.